# Como fazer um algoritmo fonético para o português brasileiro?

Tags: string, algoritmo, português-do-brasil, soundex, algoritmo-fonético

Para facilitar a busca de informações comumente grafadas erradas, usamos [algoritmos fonéticos](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_Fon%C3%A9tica). Um recurso que é extremamente útil mas que costuma ser negligenciado, especialmente fora da língua inglesa onde existem alguns algoritmos conhecidos como os citados na [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonetic_algorithm)<sup>(en)</sup>, particularmente o **Soundex** disponível em diversos DBs e linguagens.

Temos particularidades na nossa língua que inviabilizam o uso de algoritmos de outras línguas. Na verdade é até mais regionalizado. Um **algoritmo que funciona para o Brasil**, não funciona para Portugal e talvez para outros países lusófonos. Tenho até dúvidas se precisaria de especializações para o [cearense](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialeto_da_costa_norte), [gaúcho](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialeto_ga%C3%BAcho) ou mesmo para o [piracicabano](http://seumukifo.blogspot.com.br/2009/12/dicionario-piracicabano.html) e [adjacências](http://www.aprovincia.com.br/conversa-de-pescador/cultura-caipira/delicias-do-diferenciado-falar-caipira/) (de centenas de quilômetros :) ), só para citar alguns.

- Existe alguma fonte oficial, um estudo conclusivo de como deveria ser o nosso algoritmo fonético?
- Baseado nesses estudos ou por experiência, como seria esse algoritmo? Podemos aproveitar alguma variante do [Soundex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex), [Metaphone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphone) ou outro algoritmo consagrado da língua inglesa, só trocando os fonemas?
- Podemos ou devemos usar (opcionalmente) fonemas estrangeiros comuns também, já que usamos nomes estrangeiros?
- Estou interessado no algoritmo em si, portanto, como desenvolvê-lo em detalhes (não basta linhas gerais que já tem informação suficiente), um pseudo-código ou código real em alguma linguagem seria útil mas não funadamental.

Já que posso portar código de quase qualquer linguagem *mainstream*, e de fato eu vou (e outros poderão) usar em algumas linguagens diferentes, não me importa se está em C, C++, C#, Java, Javascript, PHP, Perl, Python, Ruby, Lua, Delphi, Go, D, Scala, F#, ou variantes de BASIC, xBase (Clipper, Harbour, FoxPro), SQL, etc. ou até COBOL :). Use o que já possui ou sinta-se mais confortável.

Note que o melhor algoritmo é o que vale, não a implementação, por isso não me importa a linguagem. O mesmo algoritmo em linguagem diferente será considerado duplicado.

Algumas referências que eu conheço <sub>(algumas são bem ruins)</sub>:

- [Busca Fonética em Português do Brasil](http://www.brunoportfolio.com/arquivos/pdf/BuscaBR_Fonetica.pdf)
- [Recuperação De Informações por Similaridade de Fonemas Adaptada à Língua Portuguesa](http://www.uniritter.edu.br/graduacao/informatica/sistemas/downloads/tcc2k9/TCCII_2009_1_Roni.pdf)
- [exemplo em Delphi](http://www.devmedia.com.br/forum/soundex-em-portugues/274192)
- [exemplo em C#](http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/2237/implementando-algoritmo-buscabr.aspx)
- [outro exemplo em C#](http://eduardospaki.blogspot.com.br/2011/07/fonetica-sql-server.html)
- [exemplo VB.NET](http://www.macoratti.net/sql_sdex.htm)
- [exemplo em PHP](http://informatica.varzeapaulista.sp.gov.br/metaphone/)
- [exemplo em Java](https://github.com/timotta/elasticsearch-fonetica-portuguesa)
- [outro exemplo em C#](https://github.com/MagoMatematico/Fonetico)
- [mais um em C#](https://github.com/quicoli/Fonetiza).

<sup>Apesar de ter aceito uma resposta, acho que ainda pode surgir algo melhor e estou disposto a mudar a aceitação caso isto ocorra. Ainda quero ver sua resposta.</sup>

Comment: O algoritmo piracicabano tem que obrigatoriamente ligar o auto-falante e soltar um: "**[Pamonhas! Pamonhas! Pamonhas!](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pamonhas_de_Piracicaba)**" :) ([áudio derivado sem a melhor parte](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6icte9zKsMM) e [a desmitificação](http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/fsp/turismo/fx1902200913.htm))

Comment: Encontrei um estudo interessante de sistema de conversão de texto na respectiva transcrição fonética. Pode ser útil para se pensar numa abordagem diferente das tradicionais (soundex/metaphone). É uma tese de doutorado junto à UFSC, que é um centro importante nos estudos de linguística computacional no Brasil. https://repositorio.ufsc.br/bitstream/handle/123456789/91849/254656.pdf?sequence=1

Comment: @bfavaretto também acho. Estava guardando para depois, mas também não quis perder a oportunidade. Gosto da UFSC. Para ser uma tese bem interessante.

Comment: Não conheço muito do assunto (e por isso nem me arrisco em responder), mas aparentemente há alguns estudos/projetos relacionados ao Metaphone: http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-642-28601-8_25 e http://sourceforge.net/projects/metaphoneptbr/

Comment: @LuizVieira muito interessante. Está ajudando muito.

Comment: @bigown: Fico feliz em ajudar. :)

Comment: Quando trabalhei na Prodesp (saí de lá em 2006), um algoritmo assim foi desenvolvido para o cadastro de pessoas no sistema do Tribunal de Justiça do Estado de São Paulo. Infelizmente não consegui achar nada relacionado a isso abertamente na internet, mas [este artigo](http://www.batebyte.pr.gov.br/modules/conteudo/conteudo.php?conteudo=567) dá uma idéia geral de um algoritmo que considero semelhante ao que foi desenvolvido na Prodesp.

Comment: ... note que o algoritmo que mencionei foi realmente otimizado para o nome de pessoas.

Comment: A quantidade de sotaques distintos no Brasil é impressionantes. Com certeza o algoritmo precisa ser diferenciado para certas regiões. Onde eu vivo se fala praticamente um dialeto a parte. Boa sorte.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

A ideia por trás do "Metaphone Pt-BR" é justamente a história do sucesso e do uso de algoritmos como o soundex durante os primeiros censos americanos e a melhoria da ideia, no caso, com o surgimento do metaphone.

O nicho desse algoritmo é bem específico. Não se trata de uma representação fonética acurado, seguindo o [IPA](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfabeto_fon%C3%A9tico_internacional), mas simplificações das palavras baseado no "soa como ...". O uso, tal como o soundex, foi principalmente no cruzamento de dados textuais e identificações de nomes duplicados grafados incorretamente. A vantagem dele é de conseguir reduzir o esforço computacional necessário para se encontrar uma palavra semelhante a outra usando algoritmos como similar_text() (no PHP), levenshtein, dentre outros.

Como o Metaphone poderia ser útil nesse caso? Algoritmos como similar_text, levenshtein e outros devolvem um índice, normalmente entre 0 e 1, do grau de proximidade entre duas strings, sendo 0 igual a nenhuma semelhança e 1 a semelhança total.

Imagine então para cruzar um banco de dados de milhares de nomes de ruas, cada qual com uma média entre três a quatro palavras, com um nome de rua com mesmo tamanho médio, oriundo de outro banco de dados, que pode ter sido grafado erradamente, ou abreviado, enfim, não exatamente igual ao que você possui, seria necessário verificar a semelhança entre cada palavra e tirar uma média para a rua. Considerando que esses algoritmos de semelhança tem complexidades O(m*n) e O(n^3), então estamos diante de grandes esforços computacionais para encontrar uma única rua.

O metaphone entra nessa parte. Ao simplificar a string, reduzindo-a para um tamanho de até 4 caracteres, torna-se possível criar um "índice" para palavras semelhantes. Por exemplo, REBECA, REBBECA, RABEKA e tantas outras variações partilhariam da mesma string metaphone: RBK. Com isso, posso aplicar o algoritmo levenshtein em um conjunto reduzido (normalmente entre 1 e 2 dezenas) de palavras, reduzindo o esforço computacional necessário.

Naturalmente pode-se ter outras abordagens para se resolver o problema citado, mas o Metaphone é uma delas só exigiria ter no banco de dados uma coluna a mais para servir de índice.

A versão para o português foi feita porque o Metaphone original utiliza as regras gramaticais inglesas, então muitas palavras em português acabam caindo em grupos diferentes porque soariam diferente para um americano.

O artigo que o @Luiz-Vieira cita, nos comentários do autor da pergunta, é de minha autoria, motivados pelo trabalho participado no [REDECA](http://redeca.org.br/), onde o desafio era montar um cadastro de pessoas que pudessem ter diversos documentos, logo, nenhum deles obrigatório. Quem desenvolve sistemas sabe que normalmente o CPF, por ser único e numérico, é comumente utilizando como chave primária e evitar cadastro duplicados. A saída fonética é uma das abordagens que apareceu no grupo. Com isso, fiz um aprofundamento do algoritmo utilizando uma base de dados montada com nomes de pessoas, 1 milhão de nomes e 220.000 palavras únicas, resultando no estudo acima referido, onde entendo que 4 caracteres são suficentes e quais seriam as regras para o Metaphone Português - Brasileiro. A implementação dessas regras estão no código em C disponível no SourceForge e no JavaScript que o @João-Paraná disponibiliza.

Acredito, até pela data do projeto REDECA, essa seria uma das primeira variantes abertas para o Português Brasileiro do Metaphone, rendendo um artigo científico.

E para acrescentar resposta à pergunta, segue o link do README do código em C que contém as regras de conversão do Metaphone Pt-BR, publicadas em artigo:
http://sourceforge.net/p/metaphoneptbr/code/ci/master/tree/README

Answer (score 28):

Eu comecei a fazer um que funciona com o seguinte algoritmo:

1. Ter à disposição do sistema um banco de dados com o maior número de palavras possíveis em língua portuguesa, que pode ser conseguido em dicionários.
2. "Normalizar" a string do usuário. No meu caso, removia palavras repetidas, colocava tudo em minúsculas, removia artigos, caracteres de pontuação, preposições, conjunções, advérbios, etc. O objetivo é transformar a string o menor possível.
3. Verificar quais palavras estão nos dicionários do item 1. Estas serão mantidas na string.
4. Verificar as palavras da string  que não estão no dicionário, e tentar compará-las com as do dicionário. Esta função deve retornar uma porcentagem, e você define um limite para que duas palavras sejam consideradas "iguais". Ex: `carroça` e `carrosa`. Uma simples contagem, e checagem de ordem das letras mostra que elas são 85,714% semelhantes, logo, são "a mesma palavra". Claro que existem algoritmos melhores, e já implementados em algumas linguagens (Ex: a função [`similar_text()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.similar-text.php), em PHP.)
   Estas palavras "erradas" serão substituídas por suas semelhantes vindas do dicionário,  serão substituídas na string original.
5. Qualquer palavra na string que não foi identificada nos passos 3 ou 4 é removida.
6. Em seguida, temos uma string limpa, e com a maioria dos erros corrigidos. Ela será guardada em uma tabela que possui apenas um índice [`Fulltext`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html) que guarda "strings limpas", com o conteúdo de uma postagem de blog por exemplo, e uma chave estrangeira para, no caso, referenciar a postagem de blog de outra tabela.
7. O processo de "busca quase fonética" se dá efetuando os passos anteriores numa string enviada pelo usuário, e buscando na coluna `Fulltext`.

Uso um algoritmo semelhante em um sistema de busca, e vem dando certo até agora. Claro, buscas como o `soundex` renderiam uma tese de doutorado, é um assunto complexo, e ainda pouco abordado para as regionalidades e peculiaridades da língua portuguesa. O algoritmo acima nunca passou por uma otimização de desempenho, como utilizar cache, ou algo assim, mas pretendo fazê-lo.

Answer (score 28):

### Nomes *vs* palavras do nosso vocabulário

*Nomes próprios* estão presentes não apenas em cadastros de [pessoas físicas](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pessoa_(direito)#Pessoa_f.C3.ADsica_.28natural.29), mas também em [topônimos](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topon%C3%ADmia), nomes de ruas, etc. É um universo a parte, imenso, e o desafio mais comum nas tarefas de normalização e "casamento de registros" em bases de dados.

Já as palavras de uso geral de um texto, ou seja, do [vocabulário da nossa língua](http://www.academia.org.br/abl/cgi/cgilua.exe/sys/start.htm?sid=23), podem ser isoladas dos *nomes próprios*.

O resultado estatístico da análise de *palavras do vocabulário* difere da análise de *nomes próprios*... Nomes próprios tendem a ser "multilingues" (diferentes pronúncias e origens) ao passo que o vocabulário, mesmo com seus estrangeirismos, tem mais a cara da sua língua.

A rigor teríamos então 3 tipos de algoritmos fonéticos: otimizados para nomes próprios, otimizados para o vocabulário, e genéricos. Na prática a maioria tenta ser genérico, mas, como [bem lembrou o Jordão](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-28601-8_25), a aplicação mais usual é de agrupar *nomes próprios* similares.

### Metaphone-standards

Também tive contato com o Lawrence Philips, que criou o Metaphone em 1990,  o Double Metaphone em 2000 e o Metaphone3 em 2009.  Trocamos longos emails quando comecei a rascunhar o projeto,

** https://code.google.com/p/metaphone-standards/ **

A minha preocupação era a *interoperabilidade* de indexações tipo Metaphone em bases de dados e XML; visto que, se cada um de nós cria sua pequena variação algorítmica, para sua língua ou suas otimizações (nomes vs palavras), então as indexações ficam incompatíveis. Padronizar sempre é preciso, foi uma tentativa, e ainda está de pé, se alguém quiser ajudar a retomar o projeto.

Na troca de e-mails que tive com o Philip, entre 2011 e 2012, discutimos a respeito da "história evolutiva" dos algoritmos de *hash fonético*, e sobre a existência de padrões... E no meio disso o Philip expressou que considerava  "ele mesmo o padrão", e que não acha justo eu querer propor *novos "standards"*, desviando a atenção da empresa dele, *amorphics.com*...

Como Metaphone é apenas um deles — o @JCKödel bem lembrou aqui de outros como o "SOUNDEX-en" e o "SOUNDEX-pt" —, e eu estava tendo ajuda do Philip, aceitei mudar de nome o projeto, para algo como *"[Metaphone Recipes](https://code.google.com/p/metaphone-recipes/)"* ou *"Phonetic Hashing Recipes"* (prefiro esse último)... Até comecei, mas não tive mais tempo.

#### exemplos

Especificação formal (não implementação otimizada) de algumas variações do *Metaphone*, designadas pelo idioma (*en*=inglês, *pt*=português, *pt-BR*=português do Brasil, *es*=espanhol) e pela versão (*1*, *1.1*, *1.2*, ...):

- *[Metaphone-en version 1](https://code.google.com/p/metaphone-standards/wiki/MetaphoneEn_v1)*: de 1990 do Philips.
- *[Metaphone-en version 1.1](https://code.google.com/p/metaphone-standards/wiki/MetaphoneEn_v1_1)*: uma pequena melhora, baseada nas sugestões de Kuhn (1995). A reengenharia (para obter especificação formal) se baseou no código de Battley em Ruby.
- *[Metaphone-en version 1.2.1](https://code.google.com/p/metaphone-standards/wiki/MetaphoneEn_v1_2_1)*: é o Double Metaphone do Philips, que comecei a "traduzir" para psceudo-código, mas não tive tempo de terminar (alguém ajuda?).
- *[Metaphone-pt-BR version 1](https://code.google.com/p/metaphone-standards/wiki/MetaphonePtBr_v1)*: de ~2008, [algoritmo do pessoal da Prefeitura de Vársea Paulista](http://informatica.varzeapaulista.sp.gov.br/metaphone/). Segundo o link, eles se basearam num "Metaphone do Espanhol".
- *[Metaphone-pt-BR version 1.2](https://code.google.com/p/metaphone-standards/wiki/MetaphonePtBr_v1_2)*: foi a desenvolvida pelo Jordão em linguam C, que é ainda hoje a mais rápida, mais segura e a mais usada no Brasil.
- *Metaphone-es version 1*: ... tenho no baú guardado algoritmo (citado pelo pessoal de Vársea Paulista) de I. J. Sustaita de 2005... Se alguém disser que ajuda eu desencavo ele.
- *Metaphone-es version 2*: ... bem mais novo, 2011, de A. Mosquera, e ele diz ter tomado como base direto o *Metaphone-en version 2*, não o *Metaphone-es version 1*... precisamos avalar e registrar devidamente no projeto, fazendo a reengenharia (para psceudo-código) do [código Python dele](https://github.com/amsqr/Spanish-Metaphone/blob/master/phonetic_algorithms_es.py).

## Resposta

**à pergunta principal** (como fazer um algoritmo fonético para o português brasileiro?): "fazer um algoritmo" pode ser 1- "algoritmo de alto nivel" (especificação formal),  ou 2- "algoritmo de implementação".

- Resposta-1: crie a sua própria [MLAV - Metaphone-Language Algorithm Version](https://code.google.com/p/metaphone-standards/wiki/RuleSyntax/) seguindo as regras recomendadas, para que outros possam apreciar, discutir ou usar.  Como @Maniero comentou, podemos supor que "um algoritmo que funciona para o Brasil, não funciona para Portugal", ou seja, se alguém se esforçar pode demonstrar que existe uma MLAV "foneticamente otimizada" para o *pt-PT*, e criar o padrão (MLAV) *Metaphone-pt-PT version 1* no projeto *metaphone-standards*.
- Resposta-2: partindo de uma  *MLAV* qualquer, por exemplo a [MetaphonePtBr v1.2](https://code.google.com/p/metaphone-standards/wiki/MetaphonePtBr_v1_2), faça a sua implementação. O @JoãoParaná por exemplo fez a dele com base no  [MetaphonePtBr v1](https://code.google.com/p/metaphone-standards/wiki/MetaphonePtBr_v1) em Javascript, mas não usou [expressões regulares](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Express%C3%A3o_regular), ao passo que você poderia fazer uma outra implementação usando expressões regulares.

**à primeira subpergunta** (Existe alguma fonte oficial, um estudo conclusivo de como deveria ser o nosso algoritmo fonético?):  existe o projeto que citei, *[Metaphone-standards](https://code.google.com/p/metaphone-standards/)*, que se propunha a "oficializar" as diversas variantes; sobre "estudo conclusivo" existe o [artigo do do Jordão](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-28601-8_25), justificando a escolha pelo que batizei de [Metaphone-pt-BR version 1.2](https://code.google.com/p/metaphone-standards/wiki/MetaphonePtBr_v1_2).

**à segunda subpergunta** (Baseado nesses estudos ou por experiência, como seria esse algoritmo?): acho que cada um aqui já deu a sua opinião, só avaliar, inclusive pelos votos.

**à segunda subpergunta** (Baseado nesses estudos ou por experiência, como seria esse algoritmo?): acho que cada um aqui já deu a sua opinião, só avaliar, inclusive pelos votos.

**à terceira subpergunta** (Podemos ou devemos usar fonemas estrangeiros comuns também, já que usamos nomes estrangeiros?): vide a minha colocação acima sobre "Nomes *vs* palavras do nosso vocabulário". Pessoalmente acho que se você for indexar "texto genérico" precisa de um algoritmo genérico, que contemple nomes estrangeiros e estrangeirismos.

**à quarta subpergunta** (Estou interessado no algoritmo em si... um pseudo-código...): é a proposta do projeto *[Metaphone-standards](https://code.google.com/p/metaphone-standards/)* citado, lá você encontra o pseudo-código do idioma e versão desejados, ou expressa uma nova proposta, ainda não existente.

Answer (score 23):

O Metaphone já citado acima por @luiz-vieira é capaz de gerar strings por semelhança fonética à partir de strings. Os fontes em C podem ser vistos **[neste link.](https://code.launchpad.net/metaphoneptbr)**

Veja abaixo texto extraido do READ-ME do projeto.

> Metaphone for Brazilian Portuguese
>
> O metafone é um algoritmo de transformação de texto baseado em regras
>   fonéticas en.wikipedia.com/wiki/Metaphone. As regras foram
>   baseadas em um trabalho conjunto publicado peal Prefeitura Municipal
>   de Várzea Paulista www2.varzeapaulista.sp.gov.br/metaphone,
>   durante o projeto REDECA, voltado à infância e adolescência. Este port
>   é uma variação para o português, ao menos o brasileiro.

Recentemente tive um contato com o *Carlos Jordão* autor da Implementação e sugeri o uso de expressões regulares em JavaScript para obter uma solução que funcionasse no Browser e no Lado Servidor com Node JS. Ele achou mais apropriado uma implementação tardicional usando switch/case para controlar uma maquina de estado, já que é essa a implementação em C disponivel no repositório GIT do projeto já citado.

Ele fez o porte inicial e ajeitei numa função anonima e numa página para testes unitários e agora pode ser convertido em plugin para JQuery ou Módulo para YUI 3 ou Node.

A propósito a versão em C do Jordão pode ser usada no SGBD PostgreSQL, no PHP5 e no Debian / Ubuntu e pode ser portada para outros ambientes.

Veja o [GIST com a implementação em JavaScript](https://gist.github.com/joao-parana/8946099) da função getMeta() do módulo YUI 3 Y.Metaphone

A página de testes está [aqui nesse link](https://gist.github.com/joao-parana/8946443)

Answer (score 12):

Considerando apenas a implementação do algoritmo tenho uma função adaptada para o MySQL em que os fonemas foram analisados e melhorados conforme o passar do tempo para refletir as buscas realizadas em alguns sistemas. Ele pode conter algumas inconsistências (como no caso do "W" que não tem regra definida), mas resolve a grande maioria dos casos. Os detalhes da implementação estão comentados no decorrer do código:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS transformar_fonetica;

DELIMITER $
CREATE FUNCTION transformar_fonetica(ptexto TEXT)
RETURNS TEXT
BEGIN
  DECLARE vtexto             TEXT;
  DECLARE vtexto_apoio       TEXT;
  DECLARE vposicao_atual     INT;
  DECLARE vcaracter_anterior VARCHAR(1);
  DECLARE vcaracter_atual    VARCHAR(1);
  DECLARE vcaracter_seguinte VARCHAR(1);
  DECLARE vsom               VARCHAR(2);
  DECLARE com_acentos        VARCHAR(65);
  DECLARE sem_acentos        VARCHAR(65);

  SET vtexto = UPPER(ptexto);

  SET com_acentos = 'ŠšŽžÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝŸÞàáâãäåæèéêëìíîïñòóôõöøùúûüýÿþƒ';
  SET sem_acentos = 'SsZzAAAAAAAEEEEIIIINOOOOOOUUUUYYBaaaaaaaeeeeiiiinoooooouuuuyybf';
  SET vposicao_atual = LENGTH(com_acentos);

  -- Remove acentos
  WHILE vposicao_atual > 0 DO
    SET vtexto = REPLACE(vtexto, SUBSTRING(com_acentos, vposicao_atual, 1), SUBSTRING(sem_acentos, vposicao_atual, 1));
    SET vposicao_atual = vposicao_atual - 1;
  end while;

  -- Remove caracteres inválido
  SET vposicao_atual = 1;

  WHILE vposicao_atual <= LENGTH(vtexto) DO
    SET vcaracter_atual = SUBSTRING(vtexto, vposicao_atual, 1);

    IF INSTR('ABCÇDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ', vcaracter_atual) <> 0 THEN
      SET vtexto_apoio = CONCAT(IFNULL(vtexto_apoio, ''), vcaracter_atual);
    END IF;

    SET vposicao_atual = vposicao_atual + 1;
  END WHILE;

  SET vtexto = vtexto_apoio;

  -- Substitui os mais simples
  SET vtexto = REPLACE(vtexto, 'Ç', 'S');
  SET vtexto = REPLACE(vtexto, 'SH', 'X');
  SET vtexto = REPLACE(vtexto, 'XC', 'S');
  SET vtexto = REPLACE(vtexto, 'QU', 'K');
  SET vtexto = REPLACE(vtexto, 'CH', 'X');
  SET vtexto = REPLACE(vtexto, 'PH', 'F');
  SET vtexto = REPLACE(vtexto, 'LH', 'LI');
  SET vtexto = REPLACE(vtexto, 'NH', 'NI');

  -- Remove duplicados. Menos o S que altera o som da sílaba
  SET vposicao_atual = 1;
  SET vtexto_apoio = '';

  WHILE vposicao_atual <= LENGTH(vtexto) DO
    SET vcaracter_atual = SUBSTRING(vtexto, vposicao_atual, 1);

    IF vposicao_atual < LENGTH(vtexto) THEN
      SET vcaracter_seguinte = SUBSTRING(vtexto, vposicao_atual + 1, 1);
    ELSE -- Último caracter não tem motivo para ser verificado
      SET vcaracter_seguinte = '';
    END IF;

    IF vcaracter_atual <> vcaracter_seguinte OR vcaracter_atual <> 'S' THEN
      SET vtexto_apoio = CONCAT(vtexto_apoio, vcaracter_atual);
    END IF;

    SET vposicao_atual = vposicao_atual + 1;
  END WHILE;

  SET vtexto = vtexto_apoio;

  -- Troca caracteres pelo som
  SET vposicao_atual = 1;
  SET vtexto_apoio = '';

  WHILE vposicao_atual <= LENGTH(vtexto) DO
    SET vcaracter_atual = SUBSTRING(vtexto, vposicao_atual, 1);

    IF vposicao_atual < LENGTH(vtexto) THEN
      SET vcaracter_seguinte = SUBSTRING(vtexto, vposicao_atual + 1, 1);
    ELSE
      SET vcaracter_seguinte = '';
    END IF;

    -- "B" seguindo de qualquer caracter que não seja "A", "E", "I", "O", "U", "R" ou "Y"
    IF vcaracter_atual = 'B' AND INSTR('AEIOURY', vcaracter_seguinte) = 0 THEN
        SET vsom = 'BI';
    -- "C" seguindo de "E", "I" ou "Y"
    ELSEIF vcaracter_atual = 'C' AND INSTR('EIY', vcaracter_seguinte) <> 0 THEN
      SET vsom = 'S';
    ELSEIF vcaracter_atual = 'C' THEN
      SET vsom = 'K';
    ELSEIF vcaracter_atual = 'D'  AND INSTR('AEIOURY', vcaracter_seguinte) = 0 THEN
      SET vsom = 'DI';
    ELSEIF vcaracter_atual = 'G' AND INSTR('EIY', vcaracter_seguinte) <> 0  THEN -- GE, GI OU GY
      SET vsom = 'J';
    ELSEIF vcaracter_atual = 'G' AND vcaracter_seguinte = 'T' THEN -- GT
      SET vsom = '';
    ELSEIF vcaracter_atual = 'H' THEN -- O H é a única letra do nosso alfabeto sem valor fonético, ou seja, sem som.
      SET vsom = '';
    ELSEIF vcaracter_atual = 'N' AND INSTR('AEIOUY', vcaracter_seguinte) = 0 THEN -- Quando for seguida de uma consoante, recebe o som fechado "M"
      SET vsom = 'M';
    ELSEIF vcaracter_atual = 'P' AND INSTR('AEIOURY', vcaracter_seguinte) = 0 THEN
      SET vsom = 'PI';
    ELSEIF vcaracter_atual = 'Q' THEN
      SET vsom = 'K';
    -- QUA, QUE, QUI, QUO ou QUY
    ELSEIF IFNULL(vcaracter_anterior, '') = 'Q' AND vcaracter_atual = 'U' AND INSTR('AEIOY', vcaracter_seguinte) <> 0 THEN
      SET vsom = '';
    -- Quando se localiza entre duas vogais, tem sempre o valor da sonora "Z". Exemplo: Coisa, faisão, mausoléu, lousa, Neusa, Brasil, Sousa, cheiroso, manhoso, gasoso, etc.
    ELSEIF (IFNULL(vcaracter_anterior, '') <> '' AND INSTR('AEIOUY', IFNULL(vcaracter_anterior, '')) <> 0) AND vcaracter_atual = 'S' AND INSTR('AEIOUY', vcaracter_seguinte) <> 0 THEN
      SET vsom = 'Z';
    ELSEIF vcaracter_atual = 'S' AND vcaracter_seguinte = 'C' THEN -- "S" seguido de "C" não tem som
      SET vsom = '';
    ELSEIF vcaracter_atual = 'W' THEN -- O "W" não tem uma regra definida, podendo ser "V" ou "U" dependendo da palavra
      SET vsom = 'V';
    ELSEIF vcaracter_atual = 'X' AND INSTR('AEIOUY', vcaracter_seguinte) <> 0 THEN -- "X "seguido de vogal Exemplo: Exemplo
      SET vsom = 'Z';
    ELSEIF vcaracter_atual = 'X' AND INSTR('AEIOUY', vcaracter_seguinte) = 0 THEN -- "X" seguido de consoante. Exemplo: Exceção
      SET vsom = 'S';
    ELSEIF vcaracter_atual = 'Y' THEN
      SET vsom = 'I';
    ELSEIF vcaracter_atual = 'Z' AND INSTR('AEIOUY', vcaracter_seguinte) = 0 THEN
      SET vsom = 'S';
    ELSE
      SET vsom = vcaracter_atual;
    END IF;

    SET vcaracter_anterior = vcaracter_atual;
    SET vposicao_atual = vposicao_atual + 1;
    SET vtexto_apoio = CONCAT(vtexto_apoio, vsom);
  END WHILE;

  SET vtexto_apoio = REPLACE(vtexto_apoio, 'SS', 'S'); -- Remove o "SS" que foi utilizado para decidir se continuava como "S" ou virava "Z"
  SET vtexto = vtexto_apoio;

  RETURN vtexto;
END
$
```

Algumas saídas de exemplo:

```
NEUSA   | NEUZA
HERESIA | EREZIA
PALHA   | PALIA
QUERO   | KERO
EXIGIR  | EZIJIR
HESITAR | EZITAR
```

Algumas com erro de ortografia:

```
ÇAPO      | SAPO
EREZIA    | EREZIA
ESITAR    | EZITAR
LAGOZTA   | LAGOSTA
HORIENTAR | ORIEMTAR
```

**EDIT**

Revisando as regras resolvi executar um algoritmo parecido mas em **Java**. Percebi que o "X" também não tem uma regra definida, portanto só é possível tratar alguns casos. Adicionei também o tratamento para o *~*. O resultado foi o seguinte:

```
import java.text.Normalizer;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;

public class Fonetica {

  public String converterFrase(String frase) {
    LinkedHashSet<String> palavras;

    palavras = this.converter(frase.split(" "));

    return String.join(" ", palavras);
  }

  public LinkedHashSet<String> converter(String... palavras) {
    LinkedHashSet<String> resultado = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    for (String palavra : palavras) {
      resultado.add(this.converter(palavra));
    }

    return resultado;
  }

  public String converter(String palavra) {
    palavra = palavra.toUpperCase();

    palavra = palavra.replace("Ç", "SS");
    palavra = palavra.replace("Y", "I");
    palavra = palavra.replace("W", "V"); // "W" não tem uma regra definida, as vezes é "V", as vezes é "U"
    palavra = palavra.replace("GT", "");
    palavra = palavra.replace("Q", "K");
    palavra = palavra.replace("SH", "X");
    palavra = palavra.replace("CH", "X");
    palavra = palavra.replace("PH", "F");
    palavra = palavra.replace("LH", "LI");
    palavra = palavra.replace("NH", "NI");
    palavra = palavra.replace("H", ""); // O "H" é a única letra do nosso alfabeto sem valor fonético.

    palavra = this.removerDuplicadas(palavra);

    // Acentuações
    palavra = palavra.replaceAll("([ÃÕ])([EO])", "$1-$2"); // Separa as sílabas
    palavra = palavra.replaceAll("([ÃÕ])", "$1M");
    palavra = this.removerAcentos(palavra);

    palavra = palavra.replaceAll("([BDP])([^AEIOU]|$)", "$1I$2"); // "B", "D" e "P" mudos
    palavra = palavra.replaceAll("C([AOUR])", "K$1"); // "CA", "CO" e "CU" viram "KA", "KO" e "KU" respectivamente
    palavra = palavra.replaceAll("C([EI])", "SS$1"); // "CE" e "CI" viram "SSE" e "SSI" respecivamente
    palavra = palavra.replaceAll("C([^AEIOU]|$)", "KI$1"); // "C" mudo tem som de "KI"
    palavra = palavra.replaceAll("G([EI])", "J$1"); // "GE" e "GI" tem som de "JE" e "JI" respectivamente
    palavra = palavra.replaceAll("L([^AEIOU]|$)", "U$1"); // Quando o "L" vem antes de consoante
    palavra = palavra.replaceAll("N([^AEIOU]|$)", "M$1"); // Quando "N" for seguida de uma consoante, recebe o som fechado "M"
    palavra = palavra.replaceAll("X([^AEIOU]|$)", "SS$1"); // Quando o "X" é seguido por uma vogal, tem som de "SS"
    palavra = palavra.replaceAll("([AEIOU])S([AEIOU])", "$1Z$2");
    palavra = palavra.replaceAll("Z([^AEIOU]|$)", "SS$1"); // "Z" seguido de vogal tem som de "SS"

    palavra = palavra.replaceAll("S+", "S"); // Mais de 1 "S" vira apenas 1
    palavra = palavra.replace("OU", "O"); // Quando o "U" segue o "O" não tem som

    return palavra;
  }

  private String removerDuplicadas(String texto) {
    String[] letras = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRTUVWYXZ".split("");

    for (String letra : letras) {
      texto = texto.replaceAll(letra + "+", letra);
    }

    return texto;
  }

  private String removerAcentos(String texto) {
    texto = Normalizer.normalize(texto, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
    texto = texto.replaceAll("[\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}]", "");

    return texto;
  }
}
```

Funcionando no [**IDEONE**](http://ideone.com/6vU6Dk)

Answer (score 7):

Uma forma de se fazer busca fonética (que é a mesma utilizada pelo SQL Server na função SOUNDEX) é atribuir números aos conjuntos fonéticos da palavra.

Ex.: No SQL (que tem busca fonética em inglês):

```
SELECT 'BROWN', SOUNDEX('BROWN')
UNION
SELECT 'BRAWN', SOUNDEX('BRAWN')
```

Ambas resultam em B650.

Existem diversos artigos e até um pouco de código que tenta implementar isso em português:
http://www.scribd.com/doc/38615737/BuscaBR-Fonetica
http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/2237/implementando-algoritmo-buscabr.aspx
http://www.brunoportfolio.com/arquivos/pdf/BuscaBR_Fonetica.pdf
http://www.macoratti.net/sql_sdex.htm

Código:
http://www.devmedia.com.br/forum/soundex-em-portugues/274192

Comment: Esses links são os mesmos da pergunta?