# Como fazer uma verificação ortográfica em C#?

Tags: c#

Preciso fazer uma análise das palavras contidas em uma base de dados.
A análise consiste em promover uma verificação ortográfica apenas, mostrando um relatório na tela (gridview) com as palavras incorretas.

Nunca desenvolvi nada parecido, queria uma luz.

Posso começar o exemplo com isso:

```
string[] palavrasParaCorrigir = {"batata", "conoira", "cebola", "pimentao", "beterraba"};
```

Comment: Veja se isso te atende: [Aspell.Net](http://aspell-net.sourceforge.net/) (Observação: a versão em português está licenciada via GPL - o que pode ser problemático para integrar ao seu sistema dependendo do caso)

Comment: Você pode trabalhar com uma .dll do Word para realizar tais correções. Dê uma olha nesse link: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2469/SpellCheck-net-spell-checking-parsing-using-C

Comment: Só lembrar que as respostas são interessantes para uso Com WinForms. O WPF tem verificação ortográfica por default em seus componentes onde isto é relevante.

Comment: A sua resposta parece interessante, mas hoje ela está totalmente dependente do link. E se ele estiver fora do ar, a resposta se torna inútil para o leitor. Se você melhorá-la para incluir explicações mais detalhadas sobre como usar a DLL do Word (não tem problema copiar/traduzir dados do CodeProject, já que você cita a fonte original) e até alguns trechos de código, você ganha o meu +1. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Se não se importar pelo fato do corretor ortográfico estar sob a licença GPL, uma boa solução seria usar o [NHunspell](http://nhunspell.sourceforge.net/).

Você pode obter uma de suas últimas versões [aqui](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nhunspell/files/). Depois de adicionar a NHunspell.dll ao seu projeto, basta usar o seguinte código para fazer a verificação:

```
using (Hunspell hunspell = new Hunspell("pt_br.aff", "pt_br.dic"))
{
    bool ortografia = hunspell.Spell("palavra a ser verificada");

    if (ortografia == false) //A palavra não está escrita corretamente.
    {
        /*...*/
    }

    List<string> sugestoes = hunspell.Suggest("palavra a ser verificada"); //Definindo lista de sugestões (palavras possíveis).
}
```

Obs: Os arquivos de afixos e dicionário (.aff e .dic) podem ser encontrados [aqui](http://www.ime.usp.br/~ueda/br.ispell/).

Comment: Aceitei essa como correta por ser a alternativa mais simples de implementar.

Answer (score 14):

Provavelmente bibliotecas já existentes como o [Hunspell](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33658/NHunspell-Hunspell-for-the-NET-platform) (já citado na resposta escolhida) ou [Aspell](http://aspell-net.sourceforge.net/) irão resolver seu problema de forma rápida: estas bibliotecas existem pra várias linguagens e são usados em diversos programas.

Mas se quiser se aprofundar um pouquinho: existe um artigo excelente do Peter Norvig (diretor de pesquisas da Google) sobre o assunto: http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html

Claro, está em inglês, mas explica de maneira básica como o corretor da Google funciona quando usamos o mecanismo de busca e ele sugere uma correção.

Em resumo: o sistema é baseado em um dicionário com verificação de Código Hamming de distância 2. No caso do artigo e dos exemplos, o dicionário é um arquivo com bastante texto, onde estes estão grafados corretamente. O Peter Norvig usou, para isso, vários textos de Shakespeare.

Quando o usuário entrar uma palavra, o programa pega esta palavra, e vê se existe no dicionário. Caso sim, a palavra está correta.

Se ela não existe, ele gera vários mutantes (variações com erro), dessa palavra usando as seguintes técnicas:

- Troca a posição das letras próximas;
- Tira uma das letras, pra cada posição;
- Insere uma letra, em cada posição;
- Apaga uma letra, em cada posição.

A partir desta lista de mutantes, ele vai checar se alguma delas existe no dicionário. Aquela que existir em maior número, será a correta.

No programinha de exemplo, se mesmo assim não achar uma palavra correta, ele pega cada palavra da lista de mutantes, e gera novos mutantes. E novamente vê se algum deles existe no dicionário.

No [final do artigo](http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html), tem o código do programa em várias linguagens (na época, eu escrevi uma versão em Java e em Groovy) mas você vai ver versões pra praticamente todas as linguagens, incluindo duas versões em C#.

O único detalhe adicional é que talvez você tenha que mexer no código fonte para que o intervalo de letras não vá apenas de a-z, mas inclua também as letras com acentuação, como usamos em português.

E claro, será preciso um dicionário em português. Ou, opcionalmente, se sua lista for composta apenas de produtos, por exemplo, você pode usar, ao invés do dicionário, sua lista de produtos.

Comment: Muito boa resposta, e o artigo é ótimo. Mas demanda uma boa dose de tempo para conseguir o efeito esperado.

Comment: Há um certo endeusamento do que "vem dos caras da Google", até com razão... Mas "os caras do Português do Brasil" somos nós (!), e há um certo consenso de que 2 camadas resolvem: na primeira, com [alto *recall*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall) se usa [Metaphone-pt-BR](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/5391/4186); e na segunda, para [elevar *precision*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall), utilizam-se os algoritmos "fuzzy" citados, mas bastaria um bom "similar text" (baseado em [distância de Hamming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance)) para resolver.

Comment: @PeterKrauss Mas é o artigo e algoritmos expostos pelo Peter Norvig são exatamente baseados em distância de Hamming (no caso, ele verifica erros com distância 2).

Comment: Confirmou as minhas suspeitas :-)  Sinal que a sua explicação (me pautei apenas nela) além de didática é correta.  Todavia, não confundir... Chamei atenção das duas camadas: a primeira é que reduz o universo (em bases com milhares de "frases"), e requer saber *a priori* se é um "universo pt-BR". O Hamming (demorado e impossível de usar como indexador) só é aplicado na segunda camada, ou seja, a um conjunto pequeno/ínfimo e portanto tratável.