# Vocabulário da nossa língua, onde encontrar os dados do VOLP?

Tags: banco-de-dados, código-aberto, dados-abertos

As aplicações de dicionários completos e confiáveis são imensas (nem é preciso elencá-las aqui!)... A nossa língua, ao contrário do inglês e outras tantas sem uma "referência oficial", é normatizada, e tem um importante *vocabulário de referência*, que simplificaria a vida dos programadores e usuários de bases de dados linguísticas.

## Pergunta

No Brasil (em Portugal dizem que é similar) os livros escolares, os softwares de correção ortográfica, etc. todos são (indiretamente) obrigados, por Lei, a cumprir com a ortografia expressa no [VOLP - Vocabulário Ortográfico da Língua Portuguesa](http://www.academia.org.br/abl/cgi/cgilua.exe/sys/start.htm?sid=23). São ~381.000 verbetes (ver link): *onde estão eles?*

*Alguém sabe onde ou como posso conseguir o VOLP (para download ou em CD) em XML, SQL ou outro formato estruturado?* Na verdade **não precisa ser "o VOLP", basta ser um *vocabulário sério e confiável* (ex. bases do [Unitex](http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~unitex/) ou do [Vero](http://pt-br.libreoffice.org/projetos/projeto-vero-verificador-ortografico/)) com um *flag* nos vocábulos oficiais do VOLP**.

Comment: Peter Krauss, não diretamente relacionada a sua pergunta, mas se sua correção não for baseada na VOLP, talvez [esta resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8490/como-fazer-uma-verificacao-ortografica-em-c/8519#8519) que eu dei em outra pergunta seja útil de alguma forma.

Comment: @Bacco Infelizmente aqui no Brasil é comum a situção em que, por lei, você precisa seguir um certo padrão ou norma técnica, mas as informações sobre esse padrão precisam ser **compradas** - pois estando sujeitas ao *copyright* não podem ser **copiadas**. O mesmo vale para diversos dados oficiais, como [os códigos postais](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/400/215). Isso é um baita empecilho ao progresso, pois muitas soluções informatizadas tornam-se inviáveis e/ou proibitivamente caras - pois ainda que os **meios técnicos** estejam prontamente disponíveis, você fica barrado por aspectos jurídicos.

Comment: @Bacco OK, eu estava justamente **concordando** com você ("mas não sei como ficam os aspectos legais"). Não pareceu que você estava estimulando nada ilegal não, desculpe se passei essa impressão!

Comment: @RaelGugelminCunha, meu problema não é meramente correção, é bem mais amplo, e sei de diversas outras aplicações que requerem o VOLP para "certificarem em conformidade com a Lei". A sua sugestão acho que se insere, e está bem mais relacionada, à [discussão que tivemos sobre o Metaphone](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1828/4186).

Comment: @Bacco e mgibsonbr: estou editando a questão... Vejam se com as notas consigo arrancar dos nossos leitores umas respostas, mesmo que apenas para discutir o tema.

Comment: Existem alguns *corpora* de texto em português extraídos de diversas fontes como jornais e revistas que cientistas usam para fins diversos (como a construção de analisadores de SPAM, por exemplo). Naturalmente não são oficiais como o VOLP, mas talvez sejam uma alternativa útil para outras necessidades além de dicionários. Exemplos: [CETEM (PT)](http://www.linguateca.pt/cetempublico/), [CETEM/Folha (BR)](http://www.linguateca.pt/cetenfolha/index_info.html) e [LAEL (BR)](http://www2.lael.pucsp.br/corpora/bp/index.htm)

Comment: @LuizVieira, A seleção e organização de *corpus* linguísticos é muito importantes para estabelecer a relevância (frequência de uso), ainda negligenciada pelo VOLP: nele não encontramos termos relevantes como "meio ambiente" (aparece em leis federais, obras científicas, jornalísticas, etc.) mas encontramos termos arcaicos e de relevância nula como "meio corpo de armas". O foco da minha pergunta, todavia, é a **certificação** (desculpe apontei isso apenas nas [Notas/Contextualização](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/12754/4186)): preciso certificar quais termos de um texto são oficiais e quais não.

Comment: @PeterKrauss Ah, ok. :) Eu acho que a sua pergunta estava até bastante clara, na verdade. Eu só me perguntei se os *corpus* (esse é o plural correto, né? desculpe) linguísticos poderiam ajudar em outros tipos de necessidade e se por isso valeria a menção por aqui. Mas como não sou real conhecedor do assunto preferi apenas comentar.

Comment: Tentei entrar em contato com a ABL pelo site e por e-mail sem resultado. Ainda falta tentar por telefone...

Comment: @MiguelAngelo, já tentei tempos atrás, não custa insistir... Talvez, até aproveitando que você está no Rio, o melhor seja se informar mesmo por telefone, solicitando que ao menos confirmem (as conclusões que escrevemos por aqui).

Answer (score 11):

**(ISSO NÃO É RESPOSTA!)**

As notas a seguir são subsídios para as respostas, e também um retorno para aos comentários postados na pergunta. É um texto *Wiki*: você pode colaborar revisando e ampliando!

## NOTAS DE SUBSÍDIO

Este é um texto aberto (Wiki) para subsidiar a questão geral do *[acesso livre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_access)* ao [VOLP](http://www.academia.org.br/abl/cgi/cgilua.exe/sys/start.htm?sid=19) (ou ao [VOP](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/?action=vop&page=info)), patrimônio das nações e dos falantes da língua portuguesa.

Como a maioria de nós não está familiarizado, é preciso iniciar por uma certa revisão sobre leis, vocabulários e dicionários abertos de confiança. Pode-se reparar pelos  comentários que a questão não é meramente técnica. A opção nestas *notas de subsídio* foi por incentivar o [rumo tomado em questões similares](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/5391/4186), onde se discute mais que se responde. Todos os leitores e respondentes estão convidados a  editarem também o texto das presentes notas.

### Direito autoral e vigência

(em resposta a @Bacco) Sobre a **obrigatoriedade** e sua vigência. Segundo a versão consolidada de [diversas fontes na Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acordo_Ortogr%C3%A1fico_de_1990) e [Leis oficiais do LexML](http://www.lexml.gov.br):

- O *"Acordo Ortográfico de 1990"* foi [promulgado pelo Congresso Nacional em 18 de abril de 1995](http://www.lexml.gov.br/urn/urn:lex:br:federal:decreto.legislativo:1995-04-18;54);
- Para implementar o referido Acordo Ortográfico, editaram-se, aqui no Brasil, os Decretos federais [6.583](http://www.lexml.gov.br/urn/urn:lex:br:federal:decreto:2008-09-29;6583), [6.584](http://www.lexml.gov.br/urn/urn:lex:br:federal:decreto:2008;6584) e [6.585](http://www.lexml.gov.br/urn/urn:lex:br:federal:decreto:2008;6585), e [se aprovou o Protocolo Modificativo ao mencionado acordo](http://www.migalhas.com.br/Gramatigalhas/10,MI141638,61044-Academia+Brasileira+de+Letras+Delegacao+legal+e+autoridade).

  - O [Decreto Nº6.583 de 2008](http://www.lexml.gov.br/urn/urn%3alex%3abr%3afederal%3adecreto:2008;6583) tem como anexo "ACORDO ORTOGRÁFICO DA LÍNGUA PORTUGUESA", que estabelecia no seu artigo 2º que *"os Estados signatários tomarão (...)  as providências necessárias com vista à elaboração (...) de um vocabulário ortográfico comum da língua portuguesa"*.  Estabelece ainda que *"os vocabulários autorizados registrarão grafias alternativas admissíveis (...) é evidente que só a consulta dos vocabulários ou dicionários pode indicar"*.
  - [Decreto 6584](http://www.lexml.gov.br/urn/urn%3alex%3abr%3afederal%3adecreto:2008;6584), tem como anexo o "PROTOCOLO MODIFICATIVO AO ACORDO ORTOGRÁFICO DA LÍNGUA PORTUGUESA": dá uma nova redação apenas para os artigos 2 e 3, fixando como válidos os vocabulários elaborados *"até 1 de janeiro de 1993"*.
  - O VOLP é editado pela Academia Brasileira de Letras (ABL), a qual supostamente teria a responsabilidade legal de editá-lo: essa suposição e outras tantas sobre grafia, pronúncia, etc. oficiais do português, não constam no [Decreto Eduardo Ramos, de n. 726, de 8/12/1900](http://www.lexml.gov.br/urn/urn:lex:br:federal:decreto:1900-12-08;726), única norma citada para esse fim. Segundo [migalhas.com.br](http://www.migalhas.com.br/Gramatigalhas/10,MI141638,61044-Academia+Brasileira+de+Letras+Delegacao+legal+e+autoridade) *"... essa posição tem sido assim reconhecida sem contestações ao longo de décadas"*, ou seja, não existe lei escrita, apenas uma "tradição" no preenchimento dessa lacuna.
- O MEC foi o órgão que mais cobrou pela obrigatoriedade (e quase conseguiu nos livros didáticos brasileiros) a partir de janeiro de 2013... Não por acaso o Brasil havia se feito representar em 1990 pelo Ministro da Educação. Mas (em 2012) o governo federal, [pela Lei 7875, adiou a obrigatoriedade para 2016](http://www.lexml.gov.br/urn/urn:lex:br:federal:decreto:2012-12-27;7875).

(em resposta a @mgibsonbr)  Sobre as **contradições entre direito de cobrar *copyright* (não oferecer *download*) e o Direito Constitucional brasileiro**. Parece que a venda do VOLP é, teoricamente, inconstitucional:

- Os [fundamentos do LexML](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/LexML_Brasil#Motiva.C3.A7.C3.B5es) podem ser estendidos ao VOLP: o VOLP é citado em Lei, portanto faz parte dela. O governo tem obrigação de torná-la pública, não pode cobrar do cidadão pelo acesso à Lei.
- O cidadão brasileiro não pode alegar "ignorância da Lei": a Constituição Federeal (CF) garantiria "obrigatoriedade da publicação" (art. 37), "direito de acesso" (art. 5º, inciso XIV) e "obrigatoriedade da franquia ao acesso" (art. 216, § 2º).
- Caso precedente: [norma ABNT NBR 9050:2005 - Acessibilidade a edificações](http://www.pessoacomdeficiencia.gov.br/app/normas-abnt), e parece que também a *NBR-15575-5*, são as únicas abertas (o download do texto é oferecido). As reclamações sobre abusos da ABNT já são antigas (ver [1](http://correiobraziliense.lugarcerto.com.br/app/noticia/ultimas/2014/02/11/interna_ultimas,47948/especialista-analisa-se-normas-tecnicas-da-abnt-devem-ser-gratuitas-ou.shtml), [2](http://blogs.pini.com.br/posts/normas-tecnicas-pericias/%5B11%5D-normas-da-abnt-devem-ser-gratuitas-ou-pagas-305256-1.aspx), e dezenas de outras)... As reclamações parecem ter desencadeado uma [primeira iniciativa de abertura](http://www.secovi.com.br/noticias/acesse-gratuitamente-as-normas-tecnicas-da-abnt/7346/). O impacto do VOLP sobre todo e qualquer cidadão, todavia, é muito maior do que o impacto da restrição de acesso a uma norma ABNT, portanto mereceria maior atenção.

### Contextualização

Existem dezenas de "vocabulários não-oficiais", alguns até confiáveis e melhor estruturados que o VOLP, mas **não se prestam à certificação** (nenhum dos pesquisados contém um *flag* indicando quais são as grafias do VOLP):

- [Projeto Unitex](http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/%7Eunitex/): provavelmente o mais rigoroso e sólido  "framework para dicionários". O ideal seria trabalhar com ele... Ver [Downloads do *Unitex3.0.zip* com todos os dicionários](http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/%7Eunitex/index.php?page=3&html=download2.html), em 2013 ainda não estava atualizado para o Acordo Ortográfico de 1990.
- [Projeto Vero do LivreOffice](http://pt-br.libreoffice.org/projetos/projeto-vero-verificador-ortografico/): talvez não tão rigoroso quanto o Unitex, mas certamente hoje o mais completo (volumoso) e o que mais recebeu colaborações, revisões, verificações, etc. O [download do aplicativo](http://extensions.libreoffice.org/extension-center/vero-verificador-ortografico-e-hifenizador-em-portugues-do-brasil/pscreleasefolder.2012-01-04.1563120832/2.1.2) depende do download da ultima versão do arquivo extensão "oxt", que é em si o dado-fonte do dicionário e tudo mais. O projeto VERO, foi construído com o uso do [software Hunspell](http://hunspell.sourceforge.net/) que implementa o spell-checker do LibreOffice, do Firefox, do Chrome e diversos outros aplicativos.  O projeto VERO é a iniciativa que criou os dados linguisticos (afixos, flexões, etc.) que são processados pelo Hunspell: o arquivo mais atual do Vero, por exemplo, VeroptBRV320AOC.oxt, carrega todos os dados. Para acessa-los basta renomear o arquivo para VeroptBRV320AOC.zip e unzipar. Rodando (dica do Raimundo e seus colaboradores)  `./unmunch pt_BR.dic pt_BR.aff | sort -u > listaCompleta.txt`  obtemos uma lista completa de todas as palavras do portugues (mais completa e coerente inclusive do que o VOLP). Segundo R.S.Moura,

> ... o VERO nunca recebeu apoio da ABL. O nosso léxico é resultado do trabalho voluntário de muitos abnegados que vestiram a camisa deste Projeto, disponibilizando seus materiais acadêmicos, pesquisas, listas de termos, apontando falhas e sugerindo novas palavras, durante os oito anos de atividade do VERO" (email pessoal de abril de 2014, reprodução autorizada).

- [Recurso "words" do Unix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Words_(Unix)): no UBUNTU foi apelidado de [wordlist](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/wordlist) e fica em `/usr/share/dict/brazilian` (listar com `more`). Pode ajudar a conferir palavras, consolidar com outros dicionarios abertos, mas não parece muito confiável ou tão ativo. Instala-se com `sudo apt-get install wbrazilian`.

Dicionários propriamente ditos: possuem caráter de "ontologia" (descrição semântica das palavras), mais do que de "vocabulário"... Como em geral abrangem também o vocabulário,  se confiáveis e bem completos, podem ser tão úteis quanto vocabolários:

- [Wiktionary.org do Português](https://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/P%C3%A1gina_principal): fonte colaborativa... Pode-se avaliar pelo download (`ptwiktionary-latest-all-titles.gz`) que ainda é incompleto, além de não ter "*flag* VOLP".
- [pt-PT, Docionário de Candido de Figueiredo, de 1913](http://www.dicionario-aberto.net/): é um bom ponto de partida para a criação de um dicionário de domínio público... "sendo a edição deste dicionário de 1913, de acordo com a legislação actual sobre direitos de autor, os direitos de cópia do seu conteúdo já prescreveram, tornando-o integrante no Domínio Público"[3](http://www.dicionario-aberto.net/estaticos/about.html).

Comment: Alguém já teve contato com a base de dados do **VOC**? http://voc.iilp.cplp.org/  Aparentemente ele será o "vocabulário do português universal", substituindo o VOLP (!).

Comment: ... estamos em 2021 e nada. Um ponto de partida seria mobilizar experts para retomar o projeto Unitex, aparentemente o mais sério e organizado, gerando resultados bastante confiáveis.. Só falta atualizar um pouco.  https://github.com/UnitexGramLab/unitex-lingua/tree/master/pt-BR

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei um material muito bom no site [Léxico do Português Brasileiro - LexPorBR](http://www.lexicodoportugues.com/index.php).

Baixando o [Léxico do Português Brasileiro - Alfa, zip](http://www.lexicodoportugues.com/downloads/lexporbr_alfa_zip.zip), encontramos dentro dele o arquivo `lexporbr_alfa_txt.txt`, cuja primeira coluna traz as palavras e a segunda coluna traz a classificação gramatical de cada uma. Como eu procurava uma lista de substantivos, foi fácil filtrar, resultando em 82.097 substantivos. Todas as demais classes gramaticais estão presentes, obviamente.

EDIT

O que fiz pra extrair substantivos do arquivo acima foi, no R:

```
d = read.csv('lexporbr_alfa_txt_utf8.txt',sep='\t')
n = d[d$cat_gram == 'nom',] # 82097
length(unique(n$ortografia)) # 82097 - só pra conferir

ort = vector()
for (i in 1:nrow(n)) {
  if (i %% 1000 == 0) {
    print(i) # mostrar o progresso, já que é um pouco lento
    flush.console()
  }
  dn = d[d$ortografia == n$ortografia[i],c(1,2,4)]
  if (nrow(dn) == 1 | dn$freq_orto[dn$cat_gram == 'nom'] == max(dn$freq_orto)) {
    ort = c(ort,n$ortografia[i])
  }
}
write.table(ort,'substantivos.txt',row.names=F,col.names=F,quote=F) # 78894 linhas - cheio de lixo, é verdade, mas serve pro meu propósito atual.
```

Se alguém conseguir fazer isso usando `apply`, adoraria ver.

Espero que ajude!

Comment: Obrigado Rodrigo por indicar mais essa fonte (!), que de fato parece ser atualizada (2019).  Para baixar em Linux o ideal é converter para UTF8, `iconv -f ISO-8859-1  -t utf8 lexporbr_alfa_txt.txt > lexporbr_alfa_txtUtf8.txt`.  Olhando por alto **não me parece confiável** como vocabulário de referência **para certificações**, é mais um apanhado estatístico para fins acadêmicos... Aparentemente é uma seleção de achados em algum grande *corpus linguistico*, por isso apresenta palavras estranhas e valores de frequência. Veja a palavra "mamãe" classificada como verbo por conta de freq_orto=1.

Comment: @PeterKrauss Eu usei o Geany pra converter pra UTF-8 (inacreditável ainda usarem ISO-8859 até hoje!). De fato, tem os seus problemas. Estou descartando substantivos que apareçam também como outras classes gramaticais, com isso caiu de 82 pra 73 mil palavras. Pro meu caso de uso vai ser suficiente. Você já encontrou alguma fonte melhor, que inclua classes gramaticais?

Comment: Olá @Rodrigo! Sim, encontrei anos atrás e [usei na época com o LexML](https://projeto.lexml.gov.br/institucional/noticias/pesquisa-com-suporte-de-lexico-da-lingua-portuguesa), é o Unitex. Hoje um pouco mais atualizado, é ainda o mais sério e organizado. É mantido [neste git](https://github.com/UnitexGramLab/unitex-lingua/tree/master/pt-BR), mas para quem não conhece talvez melhor partir do software deles, https://UnitexGramLab.org/ . A USP/NILC parou de atualizar em 2015, cuidado são apenas históricos http://www.nilc.icmc.usp.br/nilc/projects/unitex-pb/web/dicionarios.html

Comment: @PeterKrauss Eu já tinha baixado esse Unitex, mas o maior arquivo que encontrei nele é DELAS_PB_2018.dic, que só tem 75 mil termos, verbos incluídos. O site da USP fala em "67.500 canônicas associadas a suas regras de flexão" (ou seja, também com verbos). Isso é bem menos que os 73 mil substantivos do link que passei. Mas se estiver melhor curado, vale a pena. O arquivo a usar é o DELAS_PB_2018.dic mesmo? Pelo que estou vendo, os substantivos estão seguidos por `,Nxxx`. Filtrar isso no R não vai ser difícil. Se for, depois coloco aqui o script. E obrigado!

Comment: Olá @Rodrigo, mesmo o DELAS_PB_2018.dic, sendo um arquivo expandido, ele tem apenas as canônicas, não contem as flexões que são geradas pelo software que indiquei. O projeto Unitex é bacana porque dá consistência à lingua, tal como no [voc.iilp.cplp.org/](https://voc.iilp.cplp.org/) ele gera as flexões por regra lógica (grafos de flexão), não por determinação de corpus linguístico. Apenas as canônicas advem de corpus. Acho que o DELAF (Dicionário de Palavras Simples Flexionadas) tem tudo, precisa usar o software  para gerar (ultimo caso no site da USP tem zip antigo).

Comment: Confira a tese do Muniz, apesar de ser de 2004 o Unitex permaneceu com os mesmos conceitos e boa parte dos padrões vigentes naquela época. Dá para entender os grafos e as diferenças do DELAS para o DELAF... Ver  tese em  https://doi.org/10.11606/D.55.2020.tde-19022020-151305 .  Aí se gostar mesmo talvez possamos construir juntos uma versão SQL ou JSON para o Unitex, muito mais prática e facil de dar manutenção. Ver  https://github.com/UnitexGramLab/unitex-lingua/issues/2

Comment: @PeterKrauss Pelo que vi, criar uma versão SQL ou JSON não é nada trivial, e está bem além das minhas necessidades no momento. Se eu precisar no futuro, aí te chamo pra tocarmos esse projeto. Obrigado!