# Dicionário Português online para efectuar requests

Tags: json, xml, dicionário

Procuro algum dicionário online em português que permita fazer `requests` como o exemplo:

```
http://www.exemplo-dicionario.com/dicionario?palavra=palavra-pretendida
```

E responder a definição da palavra.
Pode retornar informação em plain text, json ou xml.

Comment: Dependendo da sua motivação, essa pergunta também pode ter informações úteis: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10287/vocabul%C3%A1rio-da-nossa-l%C3%ADngua-onde-encontrar-os-dados-do-volp

Comment: O Google usa o Oxford Languages https://developer.oxforddictionaries.com/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O único dicionário que conheço e possui uma API pública para tal consultas é o [dicionário-aberto](http://www.dicionario-aberto.net/estaticos/api.html) o qual usa JSON como resposta da API.

Entre as opções fornecidas pelo mesmo existe:

> http://dicionario-aberto.net/search-json/palavra

**Saída:**

```
{
    "entry" : {
    "@id" : "palavra",
    "form" : {
    "orth" : "Palavra"},"sense" : 
    [{"gramGrp" : "f.",
        "def" : "Som articulado, que tem um sentido ou significação.<br/>Vocábulo; termo.<br/>Dicção ou frase.<br/>Afirmação.<br/>Fala, faculdade de exprimir as ideias por meio da voz.<br/>O discorrer.<br/>Declaração.<br/>Promessa verbal: _não falto, dou-lhe a minha palavra_.<br/>Permissão de falar: _peço a palavra_."},
        {"gramGrp" : "Loc. adv.",
            "def" : "_De palavra_, de viva voz; oralmente."},
        { "@ast" : "1",
            "gramGrp" : "Loc. adv.",
            "def" : "_Pela palavra_, absolutamente, literalmente."},
        { "@ast" : "1",
            "def" : "_Ter a palavra_, ter permissão para falar numa assembleia."},
        { "@ast" : "1",
            "def" : "_Ter palavra_, cumprir alguém aquilo a que se obriga."},
        { "@ast" : "1",
            "def" : "_Palavra de rei_, firmeza no que se diz ou promete; qualidade de quem mantém o que diz."},
        { "@ast" : "1","gramGrp" : "Loc. adv.","def" : "Sim; com certeza."}
    ],"etym" : {
        "@orig" : "lat",
        "#text" : "(Do lat. _parabola_)"
    }
    }
}
```

Além disso existe a pesquisa:

- por prefixo (http://dicionario-aberto.net/search-json?prefix=pala)
- por sufixo (http://dicionario-aberto.net/search-json?suffix=vra)
- por ambos (http://dicionario-aberto.net/search-json?suffix=vra&prefix=p)

Veja a [documentação da API](http://www.dicionario-aberto.net/estaticos/api.html) no site para mais informações.