# Erro ao chamar serviço de "auto-completar"

Tags: php, java, c#, postman

Estou finalizando um sistema e agora surgiu a necessidade de apresentar para o usuário um campo com `autocomplete`.

Então tive a ideia de utilizar o `autocomplete` do dicionario *michaelis*.

Se acessarem o [SITE](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/portugues/index.php?lingua=portugues-portugues) vão ver que tem no campo de pesquisa ao digitar aparece as sugestões de palavras.

Consegui achar o seguinte serviço
http://michaelis.uol.com.br/suggest/

Mas não estou conseguindo passar os parâmetros, podem me ajudar com esse problema?

**Edit:**

O que quero fazer é igual o site http://dictionary.cambridge.org/pt/autocomplete/english/?q=ask

Que retorna um json com as sugestões de palavras, joguem esse link no postman para verem o retorno.

Comment: Veja se o link ajuda https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/31885/dicion%C3%A1rio-portugu%C3%AAs-online-para-efectuar-requests

Comment: Marquezani, mas eu não queria o resultado da pesquisa da palavra, eu gostaria de utilizar o serviço de sugestões, conforme vai digitando vai aparecendo as palavras.

Comment: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#entry-examples

Comment: Marconcilio, já imaginou eu colocar todas as palavras em português? Se já tem o serviço basta utilizar ele.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui chamar o serviço citado da seguinte forma:

Simulei pelo navegador e verifiquei quais parâmetros eram passados para o serviço. Segue abaixo a simulação bem sucedida. Além do parâmetro **palavra**, deve passar também outros três parâmetros: **r, f e t** há também um quinto parâmetro **_csrf** mas a chamada funcionou mesmo sem ele. Observe também que o tipo de parâmetro é x-www-form-urlencoded coloco abaixo também um código c# para a chamada.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
var client = new RestClient("http://michaelis.uol.com.br/suggest/");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("postman-token", "3e206738-01a8-46b6-0952-bc776e3d1608");
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "r=0&f=0&t=0&palavra=coletor", ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Comment: Grande Alexandre! Perfeito aqui foi tbm faltava alguns parametros, só achei estranho que o meu a acentuação está errada:   {"suggestions":[{"value":"c\u00f3lera"},{"value":"colerado"},{"value":"c\u00f3lera-morbo"}]}

Comment: Esqueci de colocar mas utilizei como palavra teste "Coletor". Se resolveu, marque esta resposta como válida. ;)