# Qual a estratégia para identificar uma resposta certa, sem comparação exata de String?

Tags: c#, string

Tenho um programa em C# que é como um QUESTIONÁRIO, porém ao invés de alternativas há momentos em que o usuário deve digitar uma resposta. 
A resposta da pergunta está gravada em um banco de dados e nesse momento o programa só considera correta a resposta que contém a STRING exata salva no banco.

Como eu poderia alterar isso?
Gostaria de usar as mesmas respostas do banco, porém preciso de uma margem de aceitação nas respostas digitadas.

Comment: Podes usar algoritmos para Fuzzy matching, por exemplo Levenshtein distance, etc.
Algo mais robusto: http://lucenenet.apache.org/

Answer (score 2):

O algoritmo que o @bruno indicou nos comentarios (Levenshtein distance) é um bom algoritmo para determinar a similaridade de duas strings. Existe um outro um pouco mais robusto, chamado [Damerau-Levenshtein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance) que considera também a transposição de dois caracteres adjacentes - ou seja, tem em conta *alguns* erros ortográficos simples.

Mas eu sugiro repensar o design do questionário.

Fuzzy search, e cálculo de similaridade de strings, causam má experiência ao utilizador, neste caso. Digamos que usamos o algoritmo de Levenshtein e que determinamos que a resposta dado pelo utilizador pode diferir da resposta na base de dados em 10 caracters, máximo.

E se a minha resposta tiver 11 caracteres diferentes? Está necessariamente errada? Porque é que uma resposta com 10 caracteres diferentes está correcta, e a minha resposta não?

Além disso, estes algoritmos apenas nos dizem quantos caracteres são diferentes - mas não nos dizem quais, ou qual o seu significado. Eu posso adicionar 15 caracteres a uma resposta sem alterar o seu significado - mas também posso adicionar apenas uma vírgula, e mudar radicalmente o seu significado.

É por estas razões que a maior parte dos questionários informatizados são de escolha múltipla - e os questionários com perguntas de resposta aberta são *geralmente* analizados manualmente por um ser humano.

Answer (score 0):

Depende do quão flexíveis você quer que as respostas sejam. Isto é uma questão de projeto que depende do seu produto. Algumas ideias:

- [**Converter string para caixa baixa (minúsculo)**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.string.tolower(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [**Omitir acentos (normalização)**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ebza6ck1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [**Ignorar pontuação**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421616/how-can-i-strip-punctuation-from-a-string)
- [**Remover espaços no início e no fim da string**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/61110/c-como-remover-espa%C3%A7os-no-in%C3%ADcio-e-fim-de-uma-string/61111#61111)

Você pode tentar soluções mais avançadas, como [**verificar a similaridade entre strings**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10405/como-verificar-semelhan%C3%A7a-entre-strings) e definir certo limiar de aceitação.

Novamente, isto depende do seu projeto.

Comment: Se a pergunta for Qual foi um dos projetistas da linguagem C#? e eu responder "Jacaré anta cobra Anders(espaço)(espaço)(espaço)Hejlsberg pato", isto está correto?

Comment: ? @MarceloUchimura

Comment: Se a resposta a que o PO se refere for ABC e alguém responder XYAXBC, a resposta está certa ou errada, em sua opinião? E se alguém responder com um sinônimo para ABC, um K, por exemplo?

Comment: Como eu disse, depende do projeto. Eu dei algumas ideias. A resposta para 'Qual é a capital do Brasil?' pode ser 'brasilia', 'Brasilia', 'BRASILIA', Brasília' etc. Em todos casos, eu, pessoalmente, acho que qualquer resposta deveria ser aceita, e por isso pode-se utilizar ferramentas simples como omissão de acentos e conversão para caixa baixa. Isso depende de qual tipo de pergunta estamos lidando.

Comment: Se a pessoa responder "Salvador antes, Rio de Janeiro em seguida e atualmente, Bvrasi1ia", está incorreto? Porque, assim como quem pergunta não sabe o que esperar de resposta, a pessoa que responde não sabe exatamente o que responder.

Comment: Não sou eu que estou projetando o sistema, mas na minha opinião esta resposta estaria errada, pois eu perguntei qual É a capital do Brasil. Além disso, sem dúvida não é Bvrasi1ia. Ainda não entendi seu ponto.