# Como remover espaços no início e fim de uma string?

Tags: c#, string

Como remover qualquer número de espaços no início ou fim de uma string em C#?

Comment: Já fez alguma tentativa? Qual foi o resultado da sua tentativa?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Utilize [**String.Trim()**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/t97s7bs3(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
"    aaa    ".Trim()
// "aaa"
```

Para remover apenas espaços no **início** da string, utilize **[String.TrimStart()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.string.trimstart(v=vs.110).aspx)**

```
"    aaa    ".TrimStart()
// "aaa    "
```

Para remover apenas espaços no **fim** da string, utilize **[String.TrimEnd()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.string.trimend(v=vs.110).aspx)**

```
"    aaa    ".TrimEnd()
// "    aaa"
```

Answer (score 0):

Bem, somente no início ou fim é como o [Fábio Perez](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/61111/13687) disse, mas em toda frase pode ser assim:

```
string frase = "Isso é uma string"; // Declaramos a string
string sem = ""; // Declaramos o futuro resultado
foreach (char c in frase.ToCharArray()) // Para cada 'letra' na frase
{
    if (c != ' ') // Se a letra não for um espaço
        sem += c; // É adicionada a string final
}
Console.WriteLine(sem); // Escrevemos a string final no console
```

Isso dá o resultado:

> Issoéumastring