# Como obter o percentual de semelhança entre strings?

Tags: javascript, string, typescript, comparação

Qual a melhor maneira de comparar o nível, ou percentual de *semelhança* entre duas strings usando JavaScript ou TypeScript?

Exemplo:

```
string1 = "Este grupo é muito util para crescer profissionalmente e aprender coisas novas."

string2 = "Este grupo é muito útil para aprender coisas novas e úteis e crescer profissionalmente."
```

A função retornaria o percentual de semelhança entre `string1` e `string2`, como por exemplo: 58%

Comment: e como chega nesse 58%? o que já tentou fazer?

Comment: talvez seja preciso utilizar Machine Learning para isso.

Comment: Vc chegou a ver [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/10405/112052)?

Comment: Procure sobre algorítimo de Levenshtein ou Soundex.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi está tentando obter a porcentagem de palavras iguais. Criei esta função.

Ela rodando no Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uybxw51z/1/

```
function semelhanca(s1, s2) {
  var arr1 = s1.split(" ");
  var arr2 = s2.split(" ");

  var arrMaior = [];
  var arrMenor = [];

  if(arr1.length > arr2.length) {
    arrMaior = arr1;
    arrMenor = arr2;
  } else {
    arrMaior = arr2;
    arrMenor = arr1;
  }

  var palavrasIguais = 0;

  for(var i = 0; i < arrMaior.length; i++) {
    if(arrMenor.includes(arrMaior[i]))  
        palavrasIguais++;
  }

  return  palavrasIguais / arrMaior.length * 100 ;
}
```