# Duvida String C++

Tags: c++, string, comparação

Galera, estou tendo um problema com programação C++ Preciso saber como consigo comparar duas strings digitadas pelo usuário,

–Entrada dois textos, por exemplo: Texto e Preço –O programa tem que retornar se existe ou não existe alguma palavra em comum. –Nesse exemplo deverá retornar verdadeiro, pois existe a letra E e a letra O –Caso fosse esse exemplo: Texto e Placa –O resultado seria falso, ou não há letras em comum entre as duas palavras –Programa deverá ser feito na linguagem C++

Ex.: String1 = Texto String2 = Preço

O programa deve retornar true, pois nas 2 palavras existem E e O.

Fiz o código abaixo, mas ele só compara a string inteira, alguém consegue me ajudar?

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

  char palavra1[50] = {"texto"};
  char palavra2[50] = {"preço"};

  printf("\n\nResultado: %d\n\n", strcmp(palavra1, palavra2));

  retorn 0;
}
```

Obrigado

Comment: Faça um loop pelos caracteres da primeira palavra. E para cada caractere, faça outro loop na segunda palavra, verificando se este caractere está lá.

Comment: Talvez o interesse [Como verificar semelhança entre strings?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/10405/137387).

Answer (score 3):

Dois pontos iniciais sobre o código:

1. [`strcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) compara se as strings são iguais (e não se há letras repetidas)
2. O código está em C (o título e a `tag` indicam C++)

Pode-se implementar a comparação, a princípio, como dois loops `for`. Há de se atentar para não repetir testes. Considere-se como exemplo as palavras `tatoo` e `tatty`. Se foi testada a ocorrência da letra `t` de `tatto`, não se pode testar novamente para o segundo o `t`. Então, vão aparecer duas mensagens iguais, como `Letra t repetida`. Para checar isso, é necessário incluir mais um laço `for`.

Outra possibilidade é usar o método [`find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find). Com isso, é necessário apenas um laço `for`.

O código segue e também se encontra [aqui](https://godbolt.org/z/YYqhvozPx).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    string palavra1 = "tatoo";
    string palavra2 = "tatty";

    // Compara se o conteúdo das strings e igual
    if (palavra1 == palavra2) {
        cout << "As strings sao iguais" << endl;
    }

    // Metodo 1 
    cout << "Metodo 1" << endl; 
    string repetidas1;
    bool letraChecada = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < palavra1.size(); ++i) {                      // Percorre 'palavra1'     
        for (int k = 0; k < repetidas1.size(); ++k) {                // Testa se a letra esta entre as repetidas
            if (palavra1[i] == repetidas1[k]) {
                letraChecada = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (letraChecada) {
            letraChecada = false;
            continue;                                               // Se a letra estiver entre as repetidas não é necessário percorrer 'palavra2' e volta pro primeiro FOR                
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < palavra2.size(); ++j) {
            if (palavra1[i] == palavra2[j]) {
                cout << "Letra " << palavra1[i] << " repetida" << endl;
                repetidas1.push_back(palavra1[i]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    
    // Metodo 2
    cout << "\nMetodo 2" << endl;   
    string repetidas2;
    for (auto letter : palavra1) {                                                                     // Percorre 'palavra1'
        if ((palavra2.find(letter) != string::npos) && (repetidas2.find(letter) == string::npos)) {    // Checa se a letra esta na 'palavra2' e se nao esta entre as ja checadas
            cout << "Letra " << letter << " repetida" << endl;                                         // A letra e repetida e ainda nao esta entre as checadas: escreve
            repetidas2.push_back(letter);                                                              // Inclui a letra entre as repetidas
        }
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

Pode-se também testar o desempenho de cada método considerando uma string longa. Para isso se usou o site [quick-bench](https://quick-bench.com/) e o código se encontra [aqui](https://quick-bench.com/q/Dn4uu0_pE6iB-5DNeOk2ppqWECs). Nota-se que o método com `find` foi aproximadamente 50% mais rápido (Clang 12.0, otimização -O3).

Uma [versão alternativa](https://quick-bench.com/q/kPkIS-V3-zg5b3f3O3-uKBTaB7M) com `goto` fez com que a vantagem do método com `find` se reduzisse para 40%.