# Como fazer pesquisas de palavras similares em SQL?

Tags: sql

Vamos supor que eu tenho os seguintes dados em uma tabela:

> João
>
> Pedro
>
> Ronaldo
>
> Luiz

Se eu usar uma consulta `%like%` ele acha se o usuário digitar estritamente. Por exemplo: se ele digitar `ron` ele acha `Ronaldo`. Mas se ele digitar uma letra diferente, ex: `ronldo` (erro de digitação) ele não acha. Porém o Google (e outros) costuma achar essas palavras similares.

Há algum jeito de fazer isso em SQL, independente de banco?

Comment: Você deseja implementar isso em algum banco específico?

Comment: @gmsantos Costumo usar o Postgres, mas se existir uma solução universal, melhor.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Em alguns bancos de dados é possível fazer esse tipo de busca que é chamada de [*Fuzzy Matching*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_matching_%28computer-assisted_translation%29).

Você pode obter esse resultado através das funções `soundex()` e `difference()`. Sei que elas existem no `SQL Server` e a partir de uma rápida pesquisa descobri que ela está presente no `PostgreSQL` através do módulo [*fuzzystrmatch*](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/fuzzystrmatch.html).

A função `soundex()` retorna um código de 4 caracteres de uma string passada e a função `difference()` compara a diferença entre esses códigos, em um nível de 0 à 4, onde 0 é a correspondência exata do código:

```
CREATE TABLE s (nm text);

INSERT INTO s VALUES ('john');
INSERT INTO s VALUES ('joan');
INSERT INTO s VALUES ('wobbly');
INSERT INTO s VALUES ('jack');
INSERT INTO s VALUES ('ronaldo');

SELECT soundex('john') AS john, soundex('joan') AS joan, soundex('jack') AS jack; 
-- Retorna 'J500', 'J500' e 'J200'

SELECT * FROM s WHERE soundex(nm) = soundex('john');
-- Casa com 'jonh' e 'joan'    

SELECT * FROM s WHERE difference(s.nm, 'john') > 2;
-- Casa com 'jonh', 'joan' e 'jack'

SELECT * FROM s WHERE soundex(nm) = soundex('ronldo');
-- Casa com 'ronaldo'
```

[Exemplo no SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e0331/8)

Em alguns casos simples, `soundex()` pode resolver seu problema. De acordo com a documentação do PostgreSQL, essa função tem melhores resultados com nomes em inglês.

Para implementações mais complexas, existem outros métodos de comparação por similaridade, como `metaphone()` ou `levenshtein()` (Ver exemplos na documentação do [*fuzzystrmatch*](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/fuzzystrmatch.html)).

Nos casos mais complexos recomendo aplicar um índice do tipo [Full-Text Index](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/understanding-full-text-indexing-in-sql-server/) para uma melhor performance em bases de dados grandes.

Veja a documentação das funções [`soundex()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms187384.aspx) e [`difference()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms188753.aspx) no SQL Server.

Comment: Assunto interessante, e vlw pela resposta!

Answer (score 3):

Acrescentando algumas nuâncias à boa resposta do @gmsantos...

### Metaphone para nomes do português

[Nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1828/4186) foi amplamente discutido o  algoritmo fonético para o português, que é mais eficiente do que similaridade matemática do `difference` citado, ou de distâncias como [Hamming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight), [Levenshtein](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dist%C3%A2ncia_Levenshtein) e outros, que medem a semelhança entre strings quaisquer (até em genética usam).

A questão vai na direção de um problema mais prático e já clássico:  agrupar ou equiparar nomes próprios (nomes de rua, nomes de pessoas, etc.). Por exemplo, "João"="joao", "Sylvia"="silvia", "Luíz"="luis", etc.

A experiência de quem já trabalhou ([documentada neste artigo](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-28601-8_25)) mostra que os erros  mais frequentes, de grafia de nomes, tem origem nas confusões ortográficas que fazemos quando tentamos apenas transcrever o que ouvimos. Por isso o foco na fonética.

E a fonética dos falantes do português não é a fonética dos falantes do inglês... Assim a melhor solução é o melhor algoritmo fonético adaptado ao português... E isso existe!

Trata-se do [MetaphonePtBr](http://sourceforge.net/p/metaphoneptbr/code/ci/master/tree/README). 

(se não tiver acesso a instalar funções externas no seu server, o `Metaphone` genérico também é ainda superior ao `Soundex`).

No PostgreSQL (8.X ou 9.X), depois de instalado basta fazer

```
SELECT metaphone_ptbr('Sylvia')=metaphone_ptbr('sillvya');
-- retorna TRUE  ('SV'=='SV')
SELECT metaphone_ptbr('Sylveira')=metaphone_ptbr('sillvya');
-- retona FALSE ('SVR'!='SV')
```

A grande vantagem desse método é que a comparação pode ser "cacheada", ou seja, parte do processo pode ser armazenada antes na base de dados (o metaphone de todos os nomes), de modo que a busca por um nome dado, ou o agrupamento de similares, é muito mais rápido do que a avaliação par-a-par por funções de semelhança de string.

Como permite o agrupamento, noma base de dados com 1000 nomes por exemplo, pode-se reduzir a análise para um grupo de 10 ou 20 nomes, e sobre eles aplicar as funções mais sofisticadas (custam mais CPU) de semelhança de string.