# Pesquisa Fonética para lista telefônica

Tags: mysql, sql

Estou com um problema de pesquisa por frases, tenho um campo de busca e estou usando o operador LIKE para fazer isso, mais ele não está me servindo corretamente, tentei agora utilizar o SOUNDEX, mais ele só retorna um palavra com a mesma fonética que a outra palavra, oque eu preciso é achar um palavra entre um frase.
Segue meu código SQL.

```
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE LOWER('') LIKE LOWER('%$valor%')";
```

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1828/101 a solução que você quer nem é simples e usar recursos preparados para outras línguas também vão atrapalhar mais que ajudar. Aqui, por exemplo, precisamos fazer com que a palavra "mais" seja interpretada como "mas" porque muita gente não sabe a diferente e digitam errado :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo que entendi você não deseja realmente uma pesquisa fonética, você quer apenas uma alternativa ao `LIKE` (que não é performático, principalmente quando buscamos uma palavra no meio do texto).

Essa alternativa seria a capacidade de [Full Text Search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html)

Para criar um índice nas colunas:

```
ALTER TABLE tabela ADD FULLTEXT(meu_campo);
```

Para a busca:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela 
WHERE MATCH (meu_campo)
AGAINST ('valor' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);
```

Comment: Lendo o comentário do @bigown me parece que você quer um algoritmo com busca por semelhança dentro de frases (se for esse o intuito minha resposta está fora do contexto). Aguardo seu esclarecimento.

Comment: Isso mesmo meu caro, meu problema é buscar por semelhança dentro de uma frase.