# Problemas com acentuação e entity Framework

Tags: mysql, entity-framework

Esse é um trecho do meu método de pesquisa no banco:

```
  public dynamic GetAll(Func<TEntity, bool> predicate, int limit, ClassContexto contexto, int idEmpresa)
    {
        dynamic data = null;
        try
        {
            data = limit == 0 ? 
                (from p in contexto.Set<TEntity>() select p).Where(predicate).ToList() : 
                (from p in contexto.Set<TEntity>() select p).Where(predicate).ToList().Take(limit);
        }
```

A consulta funciona legal, o problema é que o entity framework está considerando os acentos. Ex: no banco tenho "Brás y" e "Bras x". Se passo o parâmetro de consulta sem acento, só traz um registro, o que está sem acento, mas eu preciso que traga os dois.

Estou usando MySQL, e quando faço a pesquisa direto no MySQL não há diferenciação.

Como posso resover isso?

Answer (score 2):

Tenho dois caminhos bons pra você seguir:

## Primeira Opção: Fonetizando a String

[Aqui tem uma questão em que isso é largamente debatido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1828/como-fazer-um-algoritmo-fon%C3%A9tico-para-o-portugu%C3%AAs-brasileiro). Não gosto de nenhuma das soluções, então escrevi a minha:

```cs
public static class FoneticaHelper
{
    public static String Fonetizar(String termo)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder(termo.ToUpper());

        sb.Replace("Á", "A");
        sb.Replace("À", "A");
        sb.Replace("Ã", "A");
        sb.Replace("Ê", "E");
        sb.Replace("É", "E");
        sb.Replace("Í", "I");
        sb.Replace("Ó", "O");
        sb.Replace("Õ", "O");
        sb.Replace("Ú", "U");
        sb.Replace("Y", "I");
        sb.Replace("BR", "B");
        sb.Replace("BL", "B");
        sb.Replace("PH", "F");
        sb.Replace("MG", "G");
        sb.Replace("NG", "G");
        sb.Replace("RG", "G");
        sb.Replace("GE", "J");
        sb.Replace("GI", "J");
        sb.Replace("RJ", "J");
        sb.Replace("MJ", "J");
        sb.Replace("NJ", "J");
        sb.Replace("GR", "G");
        sb.Replace("GL", "G");
        sb.Replace("CE", "S");
        sb.Replace("CI", "S");
        sb.Replace("CH", "S");
        sb.Replace("CT", "T");
        sb.Replace("CS", "S");
        sb.Replace("Q", "K");
        sb.Replace("CA", "K");
        sb.Replace("CO", "K");
        sb.Replace("CU", "K");
        sb.Replace("CK", "K");
        sb.Replace("C", "K");
        sb.Replace("LH", "L");
        sb.Replace("RM", "SM");
        sb.Replace("N", "M");
        sb.Replace("GM", "M");
        sb.Replace("MD", "M");
        sb.Replace("NH", "N");
        sb.Replace("PR", "P");
        sb.Replace("X", "S");
        sb.Replace("TS", "S");
        sb.Replace("C", "S");
        sb.Replace("Z", "S");
        sb.Replace("RS", "S");
        sb.Replace("TR", "T");
        sb.Replace("TL", "T");
        sb.Replace("LT", "T");
        sb.Replace("RT", "T");
        sb.Replace("ST", "T");
        sb.Replace("W", "V");

        int tam = sb.Length - 1;
        if (tam > -1)
        {
            switch (sb[tam])
            {
                case 'S':
                case 'Z':
                case 'R':
                case 'M':
                case 'N':
                    sb.Remove(tam, 1);
                    break;
                case 'L':
                    sb[tam] = 'U';
                    break;
            }

        }

        tam = sb.Length - 2;
        if (tam > -1)
        {
            if (sb[tam] == 'A' && sb[tam + 1] == 'O')
            {
                sb.Remove(tam, 2);
            }
        }
        // ---------
        sb.Replace("Ç", "S");

        sb.Replace("L", "R");
        /* if (!_usarVogais)
        {
            sb.Replace("A", "");
            sb.Replace("E", "");
            sb.Replace("I", "");
            sb.Replace("O", "");
            sb.Replace("U", "");
        } */
        sb.Replace("H", "");

        StringBuilder frasesaida = new StringBuilder();
        if (sb.Length <= 0) return "";
        frasesaida.Append(sb[0]);
        for (int i = 1; i <= sb.Length - 1; i += 1)
        {
            if (frasesaida[frasesaida.Length - 1] != sb[i] || char.IsDigit(sb[i]))
                frasesaida.Append(sb[i]);
        }

        return frasesaida.ToString();
    }
}
```

Fiz também o contexto fonetizar automaticamente quando o nome do campo for terminado com "Fonetizado". Por exemplo, `NomeFonetizado` recebe o valor fonetizado da coluna `Nome` automaticamente ao inserir ou atualizar um registro:

```cs
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        var context = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext;


        IEnumerable<ObjectStateEntry> objectStateEntries =
            from e in context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added | EntityState.Modified)
            where
                e.IsRelationship == false &&
                e.Entity != null &&
                typeof(IEntidade).IsAssignableFrom(e.Entity.GetType())
            select e;

        var currentTime = DateTime.Now;

        foreach (var entry in objectStateEntries)
        {
            dynamic entityBase = entry.Entity;

            if (entry.State == EntityState.Added || entityBase.DataCriacao == DateTime.MinValue)
            {
                entityBase.DataCriacao = currentTime;
                entityBase.UsuarioCriacao = HttpContext.Current != null ? HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name : "MeuUsuario";
            }

            entityBase.UltimaModificacao = currentTime;
            entityBase.UsuarioModificacao = HttpContext.Current != null ? HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name : "MeuUsuario";

            foreach (var prop in entry.Entity.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                if (prop.Name.EndsWith("Fonetizado"))
                {
                    var colunaRelacionada = prop.Name.Replace("Fonetizado", "");
                    var valorOriginal = entry.Entity.GetType().GetProperty(colunaRelacionada).GetValue(entry.Entity, null);
                    prop.SetValue(entry.Entity, FoneticaHelper.Fonetizar(valorOriginal.ToString()));
                }
            }
        }

        try
        {
            return base.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
        {
            foreach (var eve in e.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following validation errors:",
                    eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State);
                foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"",
                        ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }
            throw;
        }
    }
```

## Segunda Opção: Distância de Levenshtein

Neste algoritmo, você calcula um coeficiente de tolerância para duas strings levemente diferentes. [Aqui explica detalhadamente como fazer](http://www.dotnetperls.com/levenshtein). Se o coeficiente calculado estiver abaixo da margem máxima de tolerância, você retorna o registro.

Comment: Cigano, axei bem complexo essa abordagem, pelo que entendi terei que gravar no banco o nome fonetizado e o nome original certo ?
Acredito que seria inviavel no meu caso, o volume seria muito grande. 
Acredito que quando passo "Brás" para pesquisa, o banco devolve "Brás Cubas" e "Bras Santos", porem o entity só apresenta o que contem o acento, pois o parametro da pesquisa tinha o acento, acretido ter algum modo de dizer para o entity mostrar com e sem acento, Ja revirei muita coisa, mas nada ate agora.

Comment: Bom, se você não quer gravar, a distância de Levenshtein é o melhor caminho. Infelizmente não tem caminho fácil. Eu uso as duas abordagens, dependendo do que preciso e em qual parte do sistema.