# Busca fonética no SQL server

Tags: c#, sql-server

Estou precisando implementar busca fonética para o português (br). 
Alguém tem alguma solução para busca fonética no SQL Server com c#?

A busca deverá buscar dentro de uma string usando a função SOUNDEX ou alguma função semelhante que funcione em pt-br?

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1828/101

Comment: Já vi bastante clippeiro brasileiro usando Soundex, mas como ele é feito para a língua inglesa, não fica bom. Se bem que em quase todos os casos, o código todo ja era bem no estilo do clippeiro padrão do Brasil, então o Soundex era só um detalhe.

Comment: Mas fiz um teste e ele funciona para português mas testei o básico. acho que vai quebrar um galho, até eu implementar ou achar alguma que funcione melhor no pt-br. o problema é como buscar entre todas as palavras.

Comment: Num sentido amplo, "funciona"... Falo mais de funcionar direito mesmo, e não de criar uma impressão, por "em alguns casos funcionar".

Comment: Obrigado por informar @Bacco

Comment: @MarcoAntonioQuintal notar que a intenção é alertar para uma potêncial limitação, que nem sempre é óbvia, e de maneira alguma uma crítica à sua tentativa de usar. Até porque, o passo mais importante você deu, que é fazer a pergunta para buscar uma solução :)

Comment: Se eu achar algo interessante irei publicar a resposta. Obrigado.

Comment: Dê uma olhadinha naquele link que o @bigown postou acima, tem umas coisas lá que podem dar uma noção dos caminhos já tentados. Acho que boa parte dos programadores que querem fazer uma UX melhor passou por esse dilema já. Inclusive lá é levantada a questão de casos em que você usa para palavras em geral e quando se tratam de nomes, o que por si só ja é um universo à parte. Imagine como complicaria um algoritmo que entendesse "uóchinton" e "washington" como a mesma coisa (nome é um problema que vai muito além da Língua Portuguesa).;

Comment: Fiz uns testes aqui mas a função Soundex tá ruim demais. Vai achar nada.

Comment: Você quer a solução em SQL Server ou você quer no C#? Ou ambos?

Comment: Já faz muito tempo eu vi algumas pessoas adaptando o `metaphone` e aplicando algumas lógicas para melhorar os acertos para linguagens latinas, não acompanhei e não sei se evoluiu, eu acho que na época não era nativo do SQL, infelizmente esse tipo de função/aplicação foi pouco explorada para nossa linguagem, talvez você consiga melhorar os resultados confrontando com algoritmos de busca de similaridade como [Levenshtein](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dist%C3%A2ncia_Levenshtein), é claro a pronuncia não tem haver com quão parecido duas palavras é escrita, mas em alguns casos pode ser verdadeiro!

Answer (score 3):

Já existe um post desse [Como fazer um algoritmo fonético para o português brasileiro?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1828/como-fazer-um-algoritmo-fon%C3%A9tico-para-o-portugu%C3%AAs-brasileiro)

Mas eu já me aventurei em códigos de reconhecimento de voz sem uso do database, acho que poderia ajudar a aumentar suas opções. Se eu achar esse projeto meu, eu posto ele aqui posteriormente.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/483347/Speech-recognition-speech-to-text-text-to-speech-a

ou

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/877208/How-to-implement-voice-recognition-in-Csharp-using