# Existe algum banco de dados com a transcrição fonética das palavras do português?

Tags: natural-language

Existe alguma forma se obter a transcrição fonética das palavras do português?

Eu procuro algo semelhante ao que está [neste link](http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/cgi-bin/cmudict) que lista a pronúncia das palavras do inglês.

Comment: Eu utilizo o PostgreSQL, apesar de não ser em português, as consultas por fonética funcionam muito bem

Comment: Relacionado https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1828/101

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como fazer um algoritmo fonético para o português brasileiro?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1828/como-fazer-um-algoritmo-fon%c3%a9tico-para-o-portugu%c3%aas-brasileiro)