# Buscar pessoas com nomes similares

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou desenvolvendo um código para buscar nomes de pessoas de forma inteligente usando o operador LIKE do SQL SERVER.

Em nomes como Souza e Sousa basta usar colchetes [] Ex.:

```
select * from pessoas where nome like 'joão sou[sz]a%';
```

O exemplo acima me retorna:

```
id | nome
-----------------
10 | joão souza araujo
56 | joão sousa dos santos
```

No caso do exemplo do souza|souza era só substituir a letra, mas no Vitor|Victor em que a letra C é opcional não consegui informações sobre como montar a consulta. Esta é minha dúvida.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como fazer um algoritmo fonético para o português brasileiro?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1828/como-fazer-um-algoritmo-fon%c3%a9tico-para-o-portugu%c3%aas-brasileiro)

Comment: No Oracle utilizo a UTL_MATCH EDIT_DISTANCE e JARO_WINKLER para sql server uma busca rápida retornou 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33882620/jaro-winkler-in-sql-server

Comment: @Sorack não conhecia o algorítimo fonético. Vou pesquisar sobre

Comment: Tem uma resposta que tem o algoritmo para o `MySQL`. Eu tenho em algum lugar o mesmo exemplo pra `SQL Server`, mas tenho que procurar...

Answer (score 6):

Você pode especificar o final do nome dentro do colchetes.

```
declare @pessoas table
(
  id int,
  nome varchar(100)
)

insert into @pessoas values
(57,'Victor Sousa dos Santos'),
(57,'Vitor Souza Santos')

select * from @pessoas where nome like 'Vi[ctor]%';
--ou
select * from @pessoas where nome like 'Vi[ctor]% Sou[sz]%a [dos Santos]%';
```

Result.

```
  57    Victor Sousa dos Santos
  57    Vitor Souza Santos
```