# Checagem de URL por % de palavras corretas

Tags: php

Eu faço uma checagem:

```
if( $nomedoaluno <> str_replace(" ","-",semacentos($arrayReturn['nomedoaluno'])) ){
exit();
```

e faço a montagem da url www.foo.com/nome-do-aluno

Eu gostaria de fazer uma checagem de forma que: "Se 80% estiver correto" não encerra o programa.

É possível?

Eu pensei em separar cada palavra e checar:

```
$array=explode("-",$nomealuno);
```

Mas não sei como ficaria no código. Alguém consegue me auxiliar?

Ficou dessa forma:

```
$aluno1 = $nomedoaluno;
$aluno2 = str_replace(" ","-",semacentos($arrayReturn['nomedoaluno']));
if($porcentagem < 80){
exit();
}
```

Comment: Para calcular a % de um nome errado você precisa saber o nome correto... E se tiver um Flávio e uma Flávia, essa lógica vai entrar em 'tela azul' rs

Comment: **Relacionado:** [Como fazer um algoritmo fonético para o português brasileiro?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1828/3635) (relacionado não implica duplicidade, é apenas um assunto relacionado que pode ser interessante e aproveitado)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode estar testando isso `similar_text()`, vê se resolve o problema :

```
<?php    
    $texto1 = 'Teste com Variavel';
    $texto2 = 'Teste com Var PHP';
    $iguais = similar_text($texto1, $texto2, $porcentagem);

    echo "As duas strings tem $iguais caracteres iguais, com $porcentagem% de igualdade.";
    if($porcentagem >= 80){
        print("Atende a URL");
    }
    else{
        print("Não atende a URL");
    }
?>
```

Comment: Obrigado @Gabriel~ ! adicionei na minha pergunta como apliquei no meu sistema.